# MarkdownヘルプのMarkdownが壊れている

Tags: バグ, 完了

Markdownヘルプの[「コメントを使った返答」](https://ja.meta.stackoverflow.com/editing-help#comment-reply)にあるMarkdownが上手く表示されていません。おそらく前後に半角スペースを挿入すれば直ると思います。

---

[image: スクリーンショット]

Comment: 確認してみると表示は正しいみたいですが、具体的にどこがおかしいでしょうか？

Comment: @jmac スクリーンショットを追加しました。アンダースコアを使っている部分が上手く表示されていません。たとえば`__毎回__`の部分です。あるいは`**毎回**`と翻訳されるべきなのでしょうか？

Comment: [英語版でも同じ表示](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/editing-help#comment-reply)です。`**`や`__`は見せるべきではないと思います（チャットでのオートコンプリートの事例なんで、マークダウンより、オートコンプリート機能の説明で太文字等を利用しています）

Comment: @jmac 英語版では always の部分が太字になっていますが、日本語版の「毎回」は太字になっておらず、Markdownが表示されています。これが status-bydesign なのですか？

Comment: @unarist 申し訳ありませんでした。そこを見逃しました。編集方法を確認しています。

Answer (score 3, accepted):

マークダウンでは`_`と`*`は同じ効果がありますが、日本語になるとバグが発生します。スペースなしで`_`を使うとマークダウンとして読み取らなくなります。マークダウンはオープンソースですので、こちら側で治せませんが、代わりに`_`を`*`に変換し、正しく表示されます（次回のビルドから）。