# Markdown 編集ヘルプで斜体が反映されていない箇所がある

Tags: バグ, デザイン, markdown

[Markdown 編集ヘルプ](https://ja.meta.stackoverflow.com/editing-help)で斜体が反映されておらず、アンダーバーがそのまま残っている箇所があります。以前にも[同様の問題が発生していた](https://ja.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/2469/32986)ようなので、原因が同じだとすればアンダーバーの両側にスペースを入れることで問題は解決すると思います。私も以前これと似た問題について投稿した覚えがありますが、該当するスレッドが見つからないため、改めて投稿しておきます。

- [ベア URL](https://ja.meta.stackoverflow.com/editing-help#bare-urls)

  > Markdown パーサーに手を加えて、「裸の」URL (_全部_ではないがほとんどの場合 -- URL 内の一般的でない文字に注意) に対応しています。
- コメントの書式設定の[コメントを使った返答](https://ja.meta.stackoverflow.com/editing-help#comment-reply)

  > コメントに返答する際の返答名にはスペースを使えないため、`@山田 太郎` と_しない_で、必ず `@山田` または `@山田太郎` としてください。

Answer (score 4):

Markdown が生のまま表示される問題については、[CommonMark への切り替え案内](https://ja.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/3348) にも簡単な説明を含めましたが、 Markdown が分かち書きを前提とした仕組みなので、日本語を使う我々はその点に注意を払う必要があります。

また、Markdown が正しくレンダリングされたとしても、日本語環境の一部では斜体が適用されないケースがあります。

[Markdown や HTML を使用して投稿を書式設定するには？ | ヘルプセンター](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/formatting)

> また、メイリオなどの一部フォントでは全角文字が斜体になりません。

[メイリオはCSSでイタリック（斜体）が効かない](https://www.softel.co.jp/blogs/tech/archives/5673)

> なお、英数字だけはイタリックになるので、日本語、半角英数字が混在していると、まっすぐだったり斜体になったりが混在します。

実際に試すと以下のような結果になります。

**日本語に斜体が反映される:**

- Android + Chrome
- Windows 10 + Firefox

  Windows 10 + Firefox での表示例
  [image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

**日本語に斜体が反映されない:**

- Windows 10 + Chromium ベースのブラウザ (Chrome, Opera, Edge 等)

  Windows 10 + Chrome での表示例 (半角の英数と記号のみ斜体になっている)
  [image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

反映されないケースがある点も考慮すると、場面に応じて別の書き方を使った方がよいのかもしれません。
(太字に置き換えてしまうのは強すぎるので、`" "` などで括る等)

Comment: 自分も完全に詳しい訳では無いのですが、日本語においては[斜体の文化は無いという意見もあり](https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E6%96%9C%E4%BD%93)、一部の組版業界では使わない風習があると耳にしたことがあります。これがあるので自分は自分の書く文章では基本的には太字を使うようにしていました。翻訳の際にどうすべきかは、別途翻訳のガイドラインとして決めちゃって良いかもですね。

Answer (score 3):

この部分のヘルプは Traducir で翻訳管理されている（はず）なので、両端にスペースを入れた翻訳に変えてみました。少し待つと反映されるので直ったかどうか分かると思います。

- https://ja.traducir.win/strings/5231
- https://ja.traducir.win/strings/1431

Comment: Markdown 編集ヘルプが traducir.win で編集できる範囲だったことを失念していました...。反映が確認され次第この質問を解決済みにします。